# Try statement not running correctly?

Tags: python, smtp, python-3.4

I was making a simple program that checks if a password is correct or not, in a loop. I noticed that my **try** statement wasn't working. Here is my code:

```
listfile = open("list.txt","r")
def trial():
    for code in listfile:
        try:
            google.login(victim,"none")
            print("test")
            print("[!]Trial and error complete. Password is: %s"%code)
            break
        except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
            print("test")
            print("Incorrect password:%s"%code)
trial()
```

I know the **try** statement is working. I tested it by adding the line `print("Test")` but it did not show up when I ran it.

**EDIT:**

The try statement is now running, but it always raises an error. I know that it is doing this because it is running lines 10 and 11, by printing "Incorrect password:". I saw that it printed "Inncorrect password:" even when the password that was entered was right.

Comment: Are you sure that the listfile is not empty?

Comment: Yes, it has stuff in it, but it has multiple lines.

Comment: What is the type of the `google` object?

Comment: Might not fix the problem, but move the `listfile = open("list.txt","r")` into the `trial` function. If you call the for loop on `listfile` twice without re-opening the file, the second time it will have nothing in it.

Comment: google is just the Google smtp server. `google = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.google.com",587)`

Comment: I'll try adding the `listfile` in the function, but I don't think that would help. I removed the function before with no difference but I will see

Comment: Try commenting out `google.login(...)`?

Comment: Ok. It is a main part of my code, it is meant to be there.

Comment: @ChristianR Sure, but just see if it works without that line. Maybe something weird is happening with the `login` call.

Comment: It is the `google.login()`.So how can I solve it without removing it?

Comment: @ChristianR Does your program terminate or hang?

Comment: @pushkin `google.login()` causes the program to terminate. I also fixed a `NameError` at line 11. The variable "`password`" was not defined. It was supposed to be code. Still getting an error though. I'll update the question and include the error.

Comment: The `try:` statement always catches an error, even though I know that it shouldn't be an error. check the edit section for details.

Comment: Could it be 503 errors? I might be overloading the server in a loop, but I would like to create a efficient and fast brute force program without using `time.sleep()`, because it would slow the process down(please don't criticize for this, I checked if it was at least legal)

Comment: @ChristianR Hold on, is your password `code` or `"none"`? In your `try` block, you have a print statement that says that the password is whatever `code` is.

Comment: @pushkin I think you found the issue. I was testing it and I might have forgot to reset it

Comment: @pushkin I'll take that as an answer. Sorry for the inconvenience. forgot to check the `google.login()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your login information is not correct.

In your `try` block, you have `print("[!]Trial and error complete. Password is: %s" % code)`

But when you log in, your password is "none": `google.login(victim,"none")`

Change that line to `google.login(victim, code)`